# JSON Deserialization exception with a Map<String,Map<String,Integer[]>>

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

***This question has already been answered by
https://stackoverflow.com/users/218833/rnov***
***Thanks for the help!***

I was coding something that can serialize any object into a JSON, and I used a `Map<String,Map<String, Integer[]>>` to do the properties... Basically, if you name that map `map`, I should be able to get the map with the fields using `map.get("fields")`, this will return a `Map<String, Integer[]>`... The `String` is for the name of the field, the `Integer[]` is an array of bytes that where outputted when serializing the object using `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`... But for some reason the Jackson JSON parser (Version 2.2.3) (I'm also using Maven) throws this exception when it comes to deserializing the array of integers:

**Exception Header**
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token`

**Whole Exception (Except the JSON text, that will be down below)**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: (String)"<JSON TEXT DOWN BELOW>"; line: 3, column: 9] (through reference chain: net.qava.util.UtilsParsedJson["fields"])
```

**JSON Text generated by code.**

```json
{
"fields":{
"hey" : [-84, -19, 0, 5, 116, 0, 4, 72, 101, 121, 33],
"u" : [-84, -19, 0, 5, 112]
}
}
```

**The `net.qava.util.UtilsParsedJson` class**

```java
public class UtilsParsedJson {
    public Map<String, Map<String, Integer[]>> fields = null;
}
```

**The JSON creator**

```java
default String createJson(){
        String json = "{\n";

        // Build Fields
        json = json + "\"fields\":{\n";

        for (Field field : this.getClass().getFields()){
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String name = field.getName();
                Object thing = field.get(this);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                oos.writeObject(thing);
                byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                json = json+"\""+field.getName()+"\" : "+Arrays.toString(bytes)+",\n";
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        json = json.substring(0, json.length() - 2);

        json = json + "\n}\n}";

        System.out.println(json);

        return json;
    }
```

**The JSON decoder**

```java
default UtilsJsonOutput decodeJson(String json){
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            UtilsParsedJson upj = mapper.readValue(json, UtilsParsedJson.class);

            Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer[]> entry : (upj.fields.get("fields")).entrySet()){
                byte[] bytes = new byte[entry.getValue().length + 1];
                int p=0;
                for (int i : entry.getValue()){
                    byte b = (byte) i;
                    bytes[p] = b;
                    p++;
                }

                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
                Object object = ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
                bais.close();

                fields.put(entry.getKey(), object);
            }

            UtilsJsonOutput ups = new UtilsJsonOutput();
            ups.output.put("fields", fields);

            return ups;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

***Thanks for reading!***

Answer (score 2):

Just change `Map<String, Map<String, Integer[]>> fields` to `Map<String, Integer[]> fields`. Your `fields` property has only one level of nesting.

Or, alternatively, you can remove your `UtilsParsedJson` class altogether and just use `Map<String, Map<String, Integer[]>>` instead of it.